# How to lock on asynchronous file-writes with seperate locks per file in Rust?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, actix-web, rust-async-std

I have an actix-based API, that operates entirely async. There is one endpoint, that writes a file with a user-given filename on the filesystem (I use async-std library for async fs-operations).

My problem now is, that I run into race-conditions whenever two calls are modifying the same file. I do not want a "global" mutex that locks on each single write, because that would artificially slow down my application for no reason.

Is there a possibility to acquire a lock for each single file, in order that only write-operations for this one specific file are locked & unlocked?

Comment: You could have a global `HashMap<String, async::Mutex<()>>` that you use to synchronize access to the file. The hashmap itself would probably need to be in a `RwLock` which you write to only when you add a new entry to the hashmap.

Comment: "I do not want a "global" mutex that locks on each single write, because that would artificially slow down my application for no reason." how artificially ? that normal if you need to mutate a state.

Comment: A global Hashmap containing mutexes could be a solution, I will try this out.
@Stargateur I could answer this best by an example: Image there are very many calls on a file called "a.txt" queued up. In between there comes one call to write into "b.txt". Why should "b.txt" be waiting until the lock for "a.txt" is free?

Comment: you obviously need a mutex by file anyway at this point, use a "true" database